# How to invite multiple users when editing user account?

Tags: forms, users, 7, blocks

I've installed the [Invite](https://drupal.org/project/invite) module. I see that there is an extra block that you can active. When you do this you will see a block like this on your page:

[image]

But I would like to have this field on my `user/edit` page. And make sure that they can enter multiple e-mail addresses separated by `,` .

But how can I do this?

Comment: You'd need to alter the module code presumably - could you share what you've tried please?

Comment: @Clive [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) already accepts comma-separated addresses, and as far as I know Drupal by default uses it. So maybe no alteration is possible, and simply setting block to display on user/*/edit would be enough?

Comment: @Mołot Yep Drupal does accept comma-sep'd emails to `drupal_mail`. We need to know what the OP has tried though for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

You question consists of actually 2 questions:

1. ... have this field on my user/edit page.
2. ... enter multiple e-mail addresses separated by `,` .

To answer the 2nd question (= *... enter multiple e-mail addresses separated by `,`* ), have a look at the issue about [Multiple emails support for Invite form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1293118). The [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/invite-form-uses-only-one-email-1293118-5.patch) contained in [comment nr 5](https://www.drupal.org/node/1293118#comment-8527939) of it can be used to 
create a new invite entity for each email address. Attention: it seems that this patch still needs to be rerolled for the latest dev version (which is also what explains the "needs work" status of this issue).